# Mathematically, how proximity potential affect the nuclear cross section?

Tags: nuclear-physics, potential-energy, scattering-cross-section

I have difficulties in linking proximity potentials with the nuclear cross-section.

Comment: I was not aware of these studies. found https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037594741500041X , a review. It seems the the proximity potential is used as a specific model (one mention only). You should give a link to what you are referring. It seems complicated https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235558286_Proximity_potential_for_deformed_oriented_nuclei_Gentle_fusion_and_hugging_fusion.

Comment: here https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037594741930212X "The main objective of the present study is to study the performance of various nuclear proximity potentials in reproducing the fusion cross sections and quasi-elastic cross sections simultaneously. "